# How organize action-state flow of upload/download methods using ReSwift

Tags: ios, swift, redux, reswift

I'm building application using Redux architecture with ReSwift framework, most of applications processes described by action - reducer - state flow.
Now I have added two methods upload(image: UIImage, fileName: String) and download(fileName: String), which uploading and downloading images to Firebase storage.
So, how I can describe theses methods using Redux flow?
Well, I know how I can run downloading/uploading processes using middleware, but how I can get results of download/upload in store subscribers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create actions that will either hold the results or an error like this:

```swift
struct ImageDownloadStartAction: Action {
    let filename: String
}

struct ImageDownloadSuccessAction: Action {
    let data: Data
}

struct ImageDownloadFailureAction: Action {
    let error: Error
}


struct ImageUploadStartAction: Action {
    let image: UIImage
    let filename: String
}

struct ImageUploadSuccessAction: Action { }

struct ImageUploadFailureAction: Action {
    let error: Error
}
```

Then in your `completionHandler` or `done` block, you can use the `dispatch` function passed to the middleware to dispatch the success/failure action on the main thread (for example, `DispatchQueue.main.async`) and use the value or error in your reducer.

For example (using `PromiseKit`):

```swift
let networkMiddleware: Middleware<AppState> = { dispatch, getState in
    return { next in
        return { action in
            next(action)

            switch action {
            case let action as ImageDownloadStartAction:
                networkService.download(filename: action.filename)
                .done { // automatically called on main thread in PromiseKit
                    dispatch(ImageDownloadSuccessAction(data: $0)
                }
                .catch { // automatically called on main thread in PromiseKit
                    dispatch(ImageDownloadFailureAction(error: $0)
                }

            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Already got and implemented solution like that, but thanks for answer! PromiseKit calling handlers blocks (done, catch, finally) in main thread?

Comment: @zzheads Yes, "By default, PromiseKit handlers run on the main thread, which is serial". https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Documentation/FAQ.md